# CSS isn't used on php project in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

i'm trying to run a php project i created using windows in ubuntu 12.04LTS. For that reason i installed php5 apache2 and open_jdk_7 in my ubuntu system. The next step was to put the project (the file index.php, the directory CSS and other files and directories) inside var/www/webserver directory. Then i opened firefox and wrote myip/weserver/index.php . It indeed loaded the page but it wasn't using the css. By the way i am new in ubuntu so keep it simple if possible :/ . Any help will be really appreciated.

This is the starting part of the code tha i used on the windows version in index.php

```
<?php


    define("SUBFOLDER","");
   //has to be changed to DOCUMENT ROOT
    define("ROOT","C:\webdev\apache\htdocs");
?>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/myCSSfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>images/dit.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/search.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/button.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/button2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>js/resolutionfinder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>js/changeInputValue.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>js/ajaxcalls.js"></script>
```

And this is how i changed the second define to use it on linux. maybe i give the root path wrong?

```
<?php

    define("SUBFOLDER","/webserver");
   //has to be changed to DOCUMENT ROOT
    define("ROOT","/var/www/webserver");
?>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/myCSSfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>images/dit.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/search.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/button.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/button2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>js/resolutionfinder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>js/changeInputValue.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>js/ajaxcalls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the correct path to the CSS files. Show how your files are organized, and post the HTML.

Comment: The file css is in the same folder with index.php(which is in the folder www).

Comment: It looks correct. Are there any errors showing up in the web console?

Comment: In the web console it sais [11:41:35.818] GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/index.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 49ms] for the index.php but for all the others it sais the same thing [11:41:36.021] GET http://192.168.1.3/webserver/css/myCSSfile.css [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 2ms]

Comment: That `Forbidden` error isn't a clue to the problem? Check your `.htaccess` file to make sure you allow access to the `css` subdirectory.

Comment: I had no idea about web console befoe you said it seems so usefull. Where can i find .htaccess file? sorry linux still seem a bit weird to me .

Comment: You find it on the server, it's used as part of webserver administration.

Comment: i', trying to find more information and i saw this "avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file". is it right? should i find the httpd main server config file?

Comment: I use apache2 a a server which is in etc file but i can find that .htaccess file. could you help me locate it?

Comment: If you don't have .htaccess file, maybe the problem is in httpd.conf. Whoever configured the webserver should know how to manage these files, I'm not really an expert on this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Your OS has nothing to do with your CSS. Just check the path you are loading the CSS from, its most likely wrong.